# Python executes the kompose command and the kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kompose

I have a project that needs to read a Docker Compose service sent somewhere else and save it to `compose.yaml`, then convert it to Kubernetes YAML via `kompose` and execute it via `kubectl`, all of which require Python automation.

How can I do this?

Comment: My general experience is that it's better to rewrite your deployment configuration using native Kubernetes YAML syntax.  There are some significant differences in the deployment environments (and some Compose anti-patterns that translate incredibly badly) and you'll have a better experience not putting an automated translation into your critical path.

Comment: @DavidMaze I know that manually rewriting compose yaml to k8s yaml is the best option. It might be possible to use this method on the component itself.
However, for compose yaml saved and executed internally by the project component, they are sent by other components of project and should not be able to be manually rewritten and executed.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the comments about avoiding this if possible, but sometimes you don't have that choice. I've had to do something similar before, would highly recommend the [Python Kube Client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) for managing the kubectl commands, they have great docs!

The following code will read a `docker-compose.yaml` file string and create any services and deployments it needs to run in Kube using the Kompose command.

```py
import subprocess

import yaml
from kubernetes import client, config


def load_in_kube(compose_str):
    COMPOSE_FILE_NAME = "compose.yaml"
    with open(COMPOSE_FILE_NAME, "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(compose_str)

    # Save the output to string, rather than a file.
    output = subprocess.check_output(["kompose", "convert", "-f", COMPOSE_FILE_NAME, "--stdout"])
    yaml_output = yaml.safe_load(output)

    config.load_kube_config("service-controller/.kube/config")
    for item in yaml_output["items"]:
        if item["kind"] == "Service":
            try:
                kube_client = client.CoreV1Api()
                namespace = "default"
                kube_client.create_namespaced_service(namespace, item, pretty="true")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Exception when trying to create the service in Kube: {e}\n")
        elif item["kind"] == "Deployment":
            try:
                kube_client = client.AppsV1Api()
                namespace = "default"
                kube_client.create_namespaced_deployment(namespace, item, pretty="true")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Exception when trying to create the service in Kube: {e}\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    compose_str = """version: "3.1"
    services:
      hello-world:
        build: .
        image: hello-world-api
        container_name: hello-world
        ports:
          - "5555:5555"
        entrypoint: python api.py
        environment:
          - DEBUG=True
    """
    load_in_kube(compose_str)
```